# Why doesn't the edit box dialog fill in initial value when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I use the following code to show a edit box dialog with  initial value  on which a use can input a new description and save it.

I think that the initial value *"Hello"* will be shown on *TextField* when I click the *"Edit Description"* button, but in fact, none is shown on TextField.

What's wrong with my code?

```
@Composable
fun ScreenDetail(
) {

    var editDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var description by remember {mutableStateOf("") }

     editDialog(
         isShow = editDialog,
         onDismiss = { editDialog =false },
         onConfirm ={ ... },
         editFieldContent=description
     )


    Button(
        modifier = Modifier,
        onClick = {
            description = "Hello"
            editDialog = true
        }
    ) {
        Text("Edit Description")
    }
}



@Composable
fun editDialog(
    isShow: Boolean,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: (String) -> Unit,
    saveTitle: String = "Save",
    cancelTitle:String = "Cancel",
    dialogTitle:String ="Edit",
    editFieldTitle:String ="Input description",
    editFieldContent:String ="",
) {
    var mText by remember { mutableStateOf(editFieldContent) }

    if (isShow) {
        AlertDialog(

            confirmButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = { onConfirm(mText) })
                { Text(text = saveTitle) }
            },

            dismissButton = {
                TextButton(onClick = onDismiss)
                { Text(text = cancelTitle) }
            },

            onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
            title = { Text(text = dialogTitle) },

            text = {
                Column() {
                    Text(text = editFieldTitle)
                    TextField(
                        value = mText,
                        onValueChange = { mText = it }
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var mText by remember { mutableStateOf(editFieldContent) }
```

it doesn't get updated when `editFieldContent` changes because remember{} stores value on composition or when keys change.

Then you change mText via delegation or `using mText.value = newValue` if you don't use `by` keyword.

If you set a key, block inside remember will be recalculated when `editFieldContent` parameter of `editDialog` changes.

```
var mText by remember(editFieldContent) { mutableStateOf(editFieldContent) }
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you take a look at related questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76349663/why-doesnt-the-variable-b-change-when-a-global-variable-mydata-changed-in-andro?