# Why doesn't the variable b change when a global variable mydata changed in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The `var myData=0` is global variable, I find the `var a` will change when I click the button, but the `var b` keep the value 0, why?

BTW, I have read the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72950795/why-doesnt-the-edit-box-dialog-fill-in-initial-value-when-i-use-jetpack-compose).

In my mind,  the `var b by remember(myData){ mutableStateOf(myData) }` will be recalculated when `myData` changes because I have set a key for `remember`.

```
@Composable
fun ScreenHome(){
       var a by remember {  mutableStateOf(1)    }
       var b by remember(myData){ mutableStateOf(myData) }

        Button(
                onClick = {
                    a = a + 1
                    myData = myData + 1
                },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
         ) {
                Text(a.toString()+" "+b.toString())     // The b keep to display 0
         }

}
```

**PublicPar.Kt**

```
var myData=0
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all never use variables outside of `@Compsosable` scope to set keys.

In you code you only recompose lambda of `Button` because change in `myData` does not trigger recomposition.

If you change your function as this you will see that `MutableState` instance never changes because there is no recomposition.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ScreenHome(){
    var a by remember {  mutableStateOf(1)    }
    val b = remember(myData) { mutableStateOf(myData) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
    ) {
        
        Text(text = "b: $b")

        Button(
            onClick = {
                a = a + 1
                myData = myData + 1
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text("a: $a, myData: $myData, b: $b")     // The b keep to display 0
        }

    }
}
```

Then if you read `a` outside of Button scope you will trigger recomposition and see that **b** instance changes on each recomposition with new `MyData` assigned to `MutableState`.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ScreenHome(){
    var a by remember {  mutableStateOf(1)    }
    val b = remember(myData){ mutableStateOf(myData) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)
    ) {

        // Reading a triggers recomposition
        Text(text = "a: $a, b: $b")

        Button(
            onClick = {
                a = a + 1
                myData = myData + 1
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text("a: $a, myData: $myData, b: $b")     // The b keep to display 0
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `myData` is just a regular property, the composable has no way to know when it changes to trigger recomposition. That’s why you need to use a snapshot state holder. As suggested above.